# Livewire Mount vs. Render

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I would like to understand what is the difference between mount and render methods in Livewire components, since I have seen examples where both are used to define initial state of variables. For instance, when you instantiate a variable with records from the model, ¿which is the right place to load the data using the ORM syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `mount()` method is what's called a "lifecycle-hook". There are a few more of these kind of methods in Livewire, which are outlined in the official documentation - https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks - while the `render()` is the final method that's called to render the actual view.

The `mount()` method is the construct to the component. This is where you pass in the data that the component needs. This method is only called once, on the initialization of the component, which means its also typically where you set up initial values that aren't constants.

However, since public properties of a Livewire component can only be collections, the instance of a model, arrays or native PHP types like string and integer, you can't pass more "advanced" types that relies on a state - for example like the pagination of a query of models.

That is why you would sometimes need to pass data to the component via the `render()` method, like you would when returning data in a normal Laravel controller. Another reason to pass data here is that the data is not exposed in JavaScript, like the public properties of the component is.

The `render()` method is called at the end of every lifecycle request, but before the component dehydrates. Official documentation has more detailed information https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#render-method - the data defined here isn't a property of the class, and thereby not accessible in the other methods in the component.

So to answer your question, it depends on what type of data you are passing, if the data should be accessible in the other methods in the class or if it's sensitive such that it shouldn't be visible in the JavaScript object attached to the component.

Comment: I think this a very clear and comprehensive answer.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, I have one more question: Wouldn't it be true to say that loading a model in the render() method will execute unnecessary queries on each view refresh?. For example, if we need a list of countries to populate a select control of a form, wouldn't it be better to load the model with the mount() method, since that list never changes?

Comment: It won't make a difference, since Livewire is stateless - it only sends back and forth the model type and the ID, and so it re-hydrates on each request. That means it queries the database to populate the data that you set in your mount method when it hydrates.

Answer (score 0):

mount method is like any constructor and you can use it in multiple cases, in other you don't need it. For example, if you have a nested component into a full page component, but initially the nested properties are null or require any definition, you define it there. Is used also for the route model binding definitions but you need be clear that any definition you declare here will not be updated, hydrated or suffer any changes after you initialize the component. Mostly, this is the difference with the render method.